# Looking for polyglot opening books

Tags: opening, computer-chess, pgn, polyglot

I understand the Polyglot opening format is open source, but I can't find available opening books for polyglot. I'm looking to use a book to automatically identify (and exclude) opening moves from a program to analyze large numbers of PGN files.
Is there a reliable place existing (open-source) polyglot books are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two sources for Polyglot opening books:

1. Richard Pijl has released [his opening book](https://maughancdn.s3.amazonaws.com/chess/The%20Baron/baronbook30.zip) alongside *The Baron 3.43*, which he says is almost identical to the version that played in the 2018 WCCC. Read more about these [here](https://www.chessprogramming.net/new-version-of-the-baron-v3-43-plus-the-barons-polyglot-opening-book/).
2. Sourceforge claims to have a polyglot book collection for download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codekiddy-chess/files/Books/Polyglot%20books/Update1/polyglot-collection.7z/download). The main page is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codekiddy-chess/files/Books/Polyglot%20books/Update1/).

EDIT: Found two more [here](https://digilander.libero.it/taioscacchi/programmi/saros-page.html).

> **The openings book "[Human.bin](https://digilander.libero.it/taioscacchi/archivio/Human-polyglot.zip)".**
> This "polyglot book" is a part of Deep Saros and play very aggressive and fun line of openings, like: Grob Attack, Blackmar-Dietmer Gambit, Englund Gambit, Greco Gambit, Albin Counter Gambit, Goering Gambit, Borg Defence, Polish Defence, Damiano Defence, From Gambit, Amar/Paris Opening, Fred Defence, Barnes Opening, etc...

and

> **The openings book "[Titans.bin](https://digilander.libero.it/taioscacchi/archivio/Titans.zip)".**
> This "polyglot book" was prepared by Flavio Martin, an Italian chess player and has been very strong. Is an excellent tool for analysis, preparation and training, and a viable alternative to other openings books. It's certainly being testing!

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you so much